# python/objective-c utf8 compare differ

Tags: python, objective-c, string, utf-8, compare

A python script generates a list of sorted utf 8 strings that a Objective-c program reads.
Only problem, it seems that the ordering differs in those languages ?

in python, 'i' < 'é'`

but in objective-c `[@"i" compare:@"é"]` return 1 (`NSDescendingAscending`) (which means 'i' > 'é'`)

Any idea how to get this right ? I don't mind changing either my python code or my objective-c code
Thanks

Comment: It could have something to do with that one of the cases uses a composite character (like ´ + e = é and many chinese symbols) and the other doesn't. If so, they are actually different cases and both compares are correct.

Answer (score 2):

> in objective-c `[@"記者" compare:@"記譜"]` return -1 (`NSAscending`) (which means `'記者' > '記譜'`)

No, that's not what it means. Ascending means that, when read in order from left to right (the receiver to the argument) you're going up/later in the ordering.  So, it means the receiver is less than the argument.

From [the docs for `NSOrderedAscending`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSOrderedAscending):

> NSOrderedAscending
>   The left operand is smaller than the right operand.

Comment: Well, you edited your question since I replied so it's different.  Your question is now nonsensical because there's no such thing as `NSDescendingAscending`. I'm not sure how I can be wrong about quoting and linking to the docs, though. `NSOrderedAscending` really does mean the receiver is less than the argument. You can verify it with `NSNumber`: `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]` -> `NSOrderedAscending`

Comment: Ah ok I didn't notice that mistake in my question, sorry about that ! :) Yes you are right about what ascending and descending means, but assuming I was right too, my question was essentially "why does a compare in python differs than a compare in objective-c"
for some reason when I press Enter to add a line it sends the message and SO didn't keep my full answer last time. I added that the correct answer to this is "use compare: options:NSLiteralSearch"